# Need explanation about separating linear filters

Tags: image-processing

I'm having a hard time understanding the separation of linear filters in x and y axes. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_filter) it is possible to separate Gaussian blurlike this:

[image]

I can't understand the situation well. For starters consider the **right** side of equation. The filter says 1/16*(top left pixel + 2 * top pixel + top right pixel + ...). Now what the **left** side says? 1/4*(top  + 2 * middle + bottom) * 1/4 * (left + 2 * middle + right)?

It's clear I'm getting it wrong. now what's the right way to do it? The right side filter can be applied to every pixel. How we can apply the left side filters then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The right side filter can be applied to every pixel. How we can apply the left side filters then?

The left side performs the convolution as a two step process*.

1. Convolve each column of the input image with the vertical projection of the kernel to create an intermediate image.
2. Convolve each row of the intermediate image with the horizontal projection of the kernel.

Note these steps are commutative (rows first, columns second produces identical results). Consider the example pixels:

```
a b c
d e f
g h i
```

With the kernel you posted:

```
    |1|                      |1 2 1|
1/4 |2| * 1/4 [1 2 1] = 1/16 |2 4 2|
    |1|                      |1 2 1|
```

Using the 2D kernel (right side), the resulting cell e is:

```
1/16*(a + 2b + c + 2d + 4e + 2f + g + 2h + i)
```

With the separate kernel (left side), first process by the vertical projection:

```
ai bi ci   1/4(2a+d)   1/4(2b+e)   1/4(2c+f)
di ei fi = 1/4(a+2d+g) 1/4(b+2e+h) 1/4(c+2f+i)
gi hi ii   1/4(d+2g)   1/4(e+2h)   1/4(f+2i)
```

Next, process by the horizontal projection...here just looking at the calculation for the middle cell (ei)

```
1/16( 1*di + 2*ei + 1*fi) = 1/16(a + 2b + c + 2d + 4e + 2f + g + 2h + i)
```

Which is identical to what was arrived at with the 2d kernel.

Note that rhe left and right side of the equation posted are mathematically equal - the left side is presented as the [outer product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product) of two vectors...the right side is the result of [multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Row_vector_and_column_vector) of the left.

Comment: That's a great answer. Now everything makes sense.